# Is it required to move a domain to Google DNS in order to use certbot in kubernetes on Google Cloud platform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, certbot, dns

Follow-up to [What are trusted providers that offer wildcard certificates and associated costs to be used in an Orchestration Platform like Kubernetes?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/3609/210)

With https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager it would be possible to automatically renew certificates.

At the moment my domain is registered somewhere else than google. Is it required to move the domain to Google DNS in order to use certbot in kubernetes on Google Cloud platform?

At the moment when I add a new subdomain, e.g. abc.somedomain.com I will add a CNAME to my DNS provider. At the moment I have two subdomains and I would like to switch to kubernetes. At the moment the IPs refer to some Virtual Machine instances that reside on another provider.

**Current situation**

What I understand of Certbot is that it is able to create certificates that are valid for three months. I certbot for almost a year right now and I am happy about it. When I create a new subdomain in my DNS provider I create a CNAME and run certbot and a new certificate is created. This works fine.

**Preferred situation**

Now I would like to phase out my VM and replace it with kubernetes. I was able to create a kubernetes cluster and expose the microservice to the internet using an ingress. One the IP was exposed, it is possible to access it.

**Problems**

The problem is that I now would like to get a secure Ingress, i.e. access the microservice via https rather than http, but I am struggling to understand how to configure it in k8s.

**Attempt to solve the issue**

- A Google Cloud Platform project has been created
- A kubernetes cluster has been created
- ...
- ...
- ...

Comment: Which type of validation does wildcard cert use ? I assume it is DNS, and as such certbot will need a way to create TXT records in the target zone to validate the ownership

Comment: @Tensibai I have added an extra paragraph that describes where the current DNS records resides and they refer to an IP of a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@euank indicated that it is not required to create a DNS record on GCP in order to make it work.

https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/399